# Complex background images for Java2D applications

Tags: java-2d

I am developing a (card) game and for the background I need something fancy. On my research I found [Microsoft's Solitaire game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hcLC.jpg) with this really nice green background, which tries to imitate a card table. Actually it does this really well.

So my question is, how to replicate this in Java2D with minimum resources.

[image: Solitaire screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a background image to accomplish this effect. You can draw it just like a shape using:

[Graphics.drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)

If you dont have the resources for this, concider using a texture that you can tile.